# Bootstrap button styles margin-left:-1px when click outside that area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've use bootstrap in my project, like this below

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" autofocus>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button">search</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

and in Bootstrap, I saw :

```
.input-group-btn:last-child > .btn {
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

So I write some CSS to avoid the useless `margin-left:-1px;` but I still have a problem:

When I click the area outside the `<div class="input-group search-bar">`, the button still have a effort like `margin-left:-1px;`

I'm confused, should I write some JavaScript to avoid this?

Comment: Seems like this -1px would be to align the borders of the button group. Not sure why you would try to negate it.

Comment: You thought the elite Bootstrap development team had a "useless" statement in their stylesheet? Hooboy. Here's a fiddle showing your code. Please describe the problem you're trying to resolve. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0kaugtqe

Answer (score 2):

From the bootstrap source code on Github, these -1px styles are used when having button groups where the buttons align next to each other from doubling the border. If you place 2 buttons with a 1px border next to each other, you create visually a 2px border. The -1px shifts the button over so that the border is not doubled.

Comment from actual github source:

```
// Prevent double borders when buttons are next to each other
```

Answer (score 2):

The -1px margin is there to prevent double borders when buttons are next to each other. It's meant to be this way.

If you really need to get rid of this, you may also have to adjust some of the negative margins and/or z-index for .input-group-btn > .btn:hover, :focus, :active, :first-child, and :last-child.